# Make.exe / Android / Cocos-2d-x: No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to build the Android version of the latest cocos2d-x, but I get this error when trying to compile the native code:

```
make.exe: *** /cygdrive/h/cocos2d-x-2.2/projects/MyGame/proj.android: No such file or directory
```

I've checked that the directory does exist. I'm running Windows 7 x64 with cocos2d-x 2.2, NDK version r9b and the latest Android SDK with all updates installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One time you try to import the project from cocos2d-x templete folder->ccp.
And give the NDK_ROOT in the build_native.sh file then coplie it.......if it will running then proplem in your project

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand a thing. I do have the NDK_ROOT set correctly (it was giving errors before). The project in question is (to my understanding) the template / "hello world", at least it shows the hello world image when I run the win32 build.

Comment: Import this   \cocos2d-x-2.2\template\multi-platform-cpp this project

Comment: Okay, that project did compile correctly. What could be the problem in my own project? I created it with the project generation tool.

Comment: I never create project from project_create.py One time I try but it did not create it

Comment: You can use this templete project to create a your own project

Comment: Ah. I guess I'll do that then. Thanks. :)